# SWT/MacOsx:Handling close event from taskbar

Tags: java, macos, events, swt

Handling a close event on taskbar works in Win 7 with this code

```
    shell.addListener(SWT.Close,new Listener() {                    
       @Override  
         public void handleEvent(Event event) {}

     });
```

But doesn't work in MacOSx. I need to handle this event to prevent closing of my application from the taskbar.

How I can do this?

Comment: Just figured that  display.addListener(SWT.Close,new Listener() {                    
       @Override  
         public void handleEvent(Event event) {}

     });
works !

Comment: Better use `display.addFilter(new Listener...)`.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer. That way others can easily see it when they find this page.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that

```
display.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event)
    {
    }
});
```

works !

Comment: What is SWT.Close means and what is display, please elaborate it will he helpful.